# How to build dll in Qt creator the same way as in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dll, migrate

I have a project of a DLL in the Visual Studio written on pure C++ and STL. I have to migrate to the Qt Creator for adding some of Qt features.
For beginning I simply tried to do next steps:
1) Copy sources in a new folder
2) Manually make a .pro file with these sources
3) And add this preferences in .pro file:

1. TEMPLATE = lib
2. TARGET = LogonProvider
3. DEFINES -= UNICODE
4. DEFINES += LogonProvider_LIBRARY
5. CONFIG += dll
6. LIBS += -lsecur32 -ladvapi32 -luser32 -lole32 -lshlwapi
7. #<...> There is list of sources

It all seems good and the project has compiled and I get DLL... but DLL doesn't work and have size about 30Kb, when have to have about 1Mb (if I built it with the Visual Studio) 
As I can understand, linker can't assembly .obj files to DLL, that's why it is reduced (as a result I have much .obj files around my DLL). But there were no errors or warnings during a linking proces in the Qt Creator.
I think it is some of Qt options, but what can I do with it? How can I get the same DLL from Qt as from Visual Studio?

PS. Sorry for bad english

Comment: You do not need to migrate your project to QtCreator in order to use the Qt libraries. You can download the Qt libraries that were compiled for Visual Studio and then also install the Qt Visual Studio Add-in.

Comment: That's what I did too with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually add sources and headers to your .pro file?

There are two easy ways to achieve what you want. You can either create a new blank library project in Qt Creator (File > New File or Project > Libraries > C++ Library) which will setup the .pro file for you, and then add existing sources to the project. Or you can use Qt Visual Studio Add-in to generate the .pro file for you in Visual Studio.

For reference, here is a valid project file for a library:

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = mylib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += mylib.cpp

HEADERS += mylib.h\
        mylib_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Comment: That's what I did. I tried both variants and got the same result. Issue in default linker settings in Qt, but I can't find which linker-flag can help for me.

Comment: working dll have DllGetClassObject and DllCanUnloadNow functions, but if i build dll with Qt, then  it have not